# Distinct rows in a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple rows of the same member id. I need only distinct rows based on 2 unique columns

Ex: there are 100 different customers, the table has 1000 rows because every customer has multiple cities and segments assigned to him.
I need 100 distinct rows for these customers depending on a unique segment and city combination. There is no specific requirement for this combination, just the first from the table is fine.

So, currently the table is somewhat like this,

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is logic of choosing segment

Comment: Hi Sir, there is no logic, i just need the first segment associated with the member and the first city.

Comment: there should still be an order by to get the "first" somehow. Without that there is no guarantee of any specific order. If you want first entered maybe use your identity key, there is typically a last modified date column to use as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use row_number()

```
select * from (select *,row_number() over(partition by memberid order by sales) rn
from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, infact, I have many more fields in my actual data table part from sales so how do i go about using order by?

Comment: @priyesha i provided according to your sample data so without seeing your data it is tough to say something

Comment: thank you Sir, this works, now could you please also let me know how to add this into a temp table without having to define the whole temp table

Answer (score 1):

Handy sql-server `top(1) with ties` syntax for that

```
select top(1) with ties t.*
from table_name t
order by row_number() over(partition by memberid order by sales)
```

As you have no paticular requirement for which exactly row to select, any column will do at `order by`, it can be null as well

```
select top(1) with ties t.*
from table_name t
order by row_number() over(partition by memberid order by (select null))
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this is to use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(GROUP BY...) syntax. You have no need to use an order by, since you want an arbitrary row, but only one, for each member.

Since you need only the expected data, and not the Row_Number value, make sure that you detail the fields returned, like below:

```
SELECT 
    MemberId,
    city,
    segment,
    sales
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY MemberId) as Seq
    FROM [Status]
    ) src
WHERE Seq = 1
```

Comment: OVER (GROUP BY ?

Comment: There is no way this works. There is no such thing as GROUP BY in a windowed function. It would be PARTITION BY. And it also requires an ORDER BY.